# How do you pass a value such as R.raw.twelve_chimes from an activity to a service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, parameter-passing

If I have an mp3 file in the raw folder of res called twelve_chimes.mp3 can you show me what coding to use to pass this from my activity to a service and how to receive that passed information?

Currently I'm calling the service with this code:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

In the service, this is how I'm playing the media file:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.twelve_chimes);
player.setLooping(false);
player.start();
```

If passing R.raw.twelve_chimes is not possible, can it be done as a string that is passed in and in some way to use that string to be played in the service?

Thanks.

Truly,
Emad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Service is in the same Android package as the Activity then `R.raw.twelve_chimes` should be available to the Service: you should be able to just pass it as an Integer in the Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
i.putExtra("OPTION", R.raw.twelve_chimes);
```

and in the Service's onStartCommand:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, intent.getIntExtra("OPTION"));
player.setLooping(false);
player.start();
```

May need some changes to deal with where you're calling `player` but that should more or less work.

Comment: Hi Femi, It worked nicely! I had to add this line:    startService(i); in the activity and this in the service:    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, intent.getIntExtra("OPTION", 0)); Thanks so much. Truly, Emad

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should not place the file in the /res folder. Put it in the /assets folder of your Project. Then you can access it with the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)

The difference between the /res/raw and the /assets folder is, one can access the files in /assets as binary Streams. On the other hand, one can localize files under the /res folder.

Comment: Hi user375251, Thanks for the help. I need to look more into the assets folder. Truly, Emad